# Python : displaying the number of a value in the columns in a bar graph

Tags: python, dataframe, plot, graph

In the dataframe below, each column has an "equal" value. I need a bar graph that shows how many of these values are relative to the columns. Column names on the x plane and the total number of "equal" on the y plane. Unfortunately, I can't show it because I can't print it. thanks.

```
   result_invoiceNo result_totalGross  ... result_totalNet result_invoiceDate
0              equal             equal  ...           equal              equal
1                                       ...                                   
2              equal             equal  ...           equal              equal
3                                       ...                                   
4              equal             equal  ...           equal              equal
..               ...               ...  ...             ...                ...
183                                     ...                          not equal
184            equal             equal  ...           equal              equal
185                                     ...                                   
186            equal             equal  ...           equal              equal
```

Answer (score 0):

csv**,
I have gone through your above question and got the solution for it, if all the columns of dataframe is contains with 'equal' or 'not equal' data. that is below.

```py
import pandas as pd

#create a DataFrame 
dt_frame = pd.DataFrame({'Column_A':['equal','equal','not equal','equal','equal','equal','equal','equal','not equal','equal'],
                        'Column_B':['not equal','equal','equal','equal','not equal','equal','equal','equal','not equal','equal'],
                        'Column_C':['equal','equal','equal','equal','equal','not equal','equal','equal','not equal','equal']})

#review the DataFrame
dt_frame.head()
```

**head()** returns the top five elements from DataFrame by default.
[Top 5 records of dt_frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5CDH.png)

Convert your dataframe into below as well as.

```py
columns = dt_frame.columns  # list of the columns of dataframe
# creating a new dataframe with two columns one is 'equal' and second is 'not equal' with columns as index.
pd_dt = pd.DataFrame({'equal':[None],'not equal':[None]}, index=columns)
pd_dt  #review the new dataframe.
```

[pd_dt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKtNH.png)

Now count the values from every column of dt_frame and put the count in pd_dt columns.

```py
for c in columns:
    pd_dt.loc[c]=dt_frame[c].value_counts()
pd_dt  # review the again dataframe.
```

[final pd_dt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jif4K.png)
Now, plot the **bar** graph, pandas provides the plot function to plot the dataframe.

```py
pd_dt.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(10,10))
```

**Output**
[bar graph of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxEOf.png)